# How to search for a document in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I search the ES document from a `job_name`?
This is how the document looks like:

```
{"_index":"deedloadjobstatus","_type":"DeedExtract","_id":"AVX0UkVKNGSyAbnrJkor","_score":1.0,
 "_source":{"luigi_task_name": "DeedExtract", "job_name": "DeedDowloader2", "successful": 1, 
 "start_time": "2016-07-16T20:59:21.000Z", "error_message": null, "month": 7, "end_time": "2016-07-16T20:59:21.000Z", 
 "monthname": "Jul", "year": 2016, "runtime": 0, 
 "all_params": {"job_name": "DeedDowloader2", "run_date": "2016-07-15"}, 
 "@timestamp": "2016-07-16T20:59:21.000Z", "day": 16}}
```

I tried the below but am not able to find.

```
host:port_number/deedloadjobstatus/_search?jobname:DeedDowloader2
```

Comment: Try `host:port_number/deedloadjobstatus/_search?jobname:deeddowloader2`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work. I think you just forgot the underscore. (**job_name** and not **jobname**)

If you want, you can use term query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "job_name": "DeedDowloader2" 
    }
  }
}
```

Read this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Term query will work in this case only if `job_name` field is `analyzed`, otherwise this query will not fetch any results

Comment: I guess you mean `not_analyzed` @Richa. Term query matches the term as it is stored in the inverted index. If the field is analyzed, then you will only have results if you search for: `deeddowloader2`